# Application built on an open source IDE is also open source

Tags: web-applications, asp.net-core-mvc, open-source

**OPen Source**
I know open source software is that whose source code we can download it and edit it etc.
But my question is that if i built an application on open source IDE then that application is also open source 
e.g
I Developed a web application suppose **"stack"** on asp.netcore mvc then the stack is open source or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the license of the framework you are using, asp .netcore mvc is a framework to assist you in building your application not an IDE. Visual Studio is an [Integrated Development Environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment).

For example the license for asp.net mvc is available here:

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/LICENSE.txt

Typically open source software (project, framework or IDE) does not mandate that your software should also be open source.